# Rails 3 exclude HTML5 jwplayer js in manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jwplayer

In my application.js, I have the manifest for external js files as such

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-mousewheel.js
//= require jquery-fileupload
//= require jquery-fileupload-ui
//= require_self
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require rails.validations
//= require rails.validations.custom
//= require jwplayer
//= require jwplayer.html5
//= require jwplayer-license
```

When I run my web app in IE8, I get this error:

```
Message: 'n.sheet.cssRules' is null or not an object
```

After some searching, I traced the error back to the jwplayer.html5.js file. Is there a way to exclude this file from within application.js when IE8 is detected?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue with the same setup (Rails 3, JWPlayer 6.1.x, etc). For what it's worth, upgrading to JWPlayer 6.2.x didn't resolve the issue

I don't have a solution, but I do have a workaround. I pulled JWPlayer out of my application.js, added `<%= yield :javascripts %>` to my application.html.erb, and moved the JWPlayer includes to only the view where I needed them:

```
<% content_for :javascripts do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jwplayer" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jwplayer.html5" %>
<% end -%>
```

Note that in my case, I also had to add those files to `config.assets.precompile`.

Essentially what's happening is that IE8 (and presumably 7) is freaking out if there's no instance of JWPlayer on the page. The ideal fix would actually be for JWPlayer itself to check if that's the case instead of letting IE throw an error, but until they fix it on their end, this at least gets things working.

It's frustrating and far from an ideal solution, but it worked in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too. I did some work on the jwplayer-rails gem. I am still waiting on my pull request to go through. For now follow the info in [this readme](https://github.com/dutgriff/jwplayer-rails/blob/master/README.md) to get it up and running. Read more on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825970/jw-player-and-rails-3-2/22995473#22995473).