# jwplayer in rails error when is added in the web

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html5-video, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I already have jwplayer and I was installing following this post [JW-Player and Rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825970/jw-player-and-rails-3-2/16817568#16817568)
Once installed :

```
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="MYKEY";</script>
<div id="video">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("video").setup({
        flashplayer: "<%=asset_path('jwplayer.flash.swf')%>",
        file: "http://video.mydomain.com/videos/flv/file.f0d55b98f6e84fc00a6b862.flv",
        height: 360,
        width: 640,
        analytics: {
            enabled: false,
            cookies: false
        }
    });
</script>
```

and then the "video screen" is black and I have the following message

```
Started GET "/jwplayer.flash.swf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-28 17:23:20 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/jwplayer.flash.swf"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Thank you very much for your help and time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app/assets directory create a folder named as "jwplayer" and put jwplayer.flash.swf in it.
So that the directory structure looks like app/assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf. 
And also update the browser to latest version otherwise it will not support HTML5.

If it will still throw the same error then keep the changes as it is and replace the line

flashplayer: "<%=asset_path('jwplayer.flash.swf')%>" with

flashplayer: "<%=asset_path('jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf')%>"